# Ember.js Send action from controller to component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatables

I'm writing an Ember App with jQuery Datatables. 
 
I want to send the action from the controller to refresh the table, I've used Ember Component Inbound Actions. Here is my Code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import InboundActions from 'ember-component-inbound-actions/inbound-actions';

export default Ember.Component.extend(InboundActions,{
  init() {
     this._super(...arguments);
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    var table = this.$('#example').DataTable({
      var _this=this;
    })
  },

  actions: {
    check: function() {
      this.table.ajax.reload( null, false );
    }
  },
});
```

The result is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

How to properly use this action to reload the datatables?

Comment: You are not setting the table property of the component anywhere, that's why it's undefined. You need to do something like `this.set('table', table')` in the `didInsertElement` method.

Comment: That's the correct answer, Setting the table using this.set works great. Greetings, Rafał